# Using Line Integrals to solve Amperes Law

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, line-integrals, electromagnetism

I have been reading the forums on how to solve the integral form of ampere's law and I have worked out that the correct way to solve it is to get rid of the dot product by realizing that $|B ∙ dr|$ is always $B dr$ because $\cos\theta$ is always $0$. The integrate across the circle. However my problem is that I original tried to solve this like any other line integral with the attached work. Somebody please explain why my reasoning is incorrect. I am new to vector calculus and am teaching myself so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Attempt at a solution:**

$$\int_C B\cdot dr = \mu_0I = \int_{t=a}^{t=b} B(\vec r(t))\cdot \vec r'(t)dt$$

$C$ is any circle with radius $r$.  $x=r\cos(t)$, $y=r\sin(t)$.

$$\vec r(t) = r\cos(t)\hat i + r\sin(t)\hat j \\ \vec r'(t) = -r\sin(t)\hat i + r\cos(t)\hat j$$

Let $\vec B = \langle B_1, B_2\rangle$.

$$\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} \langle B_1, B_2\rangle \cdot \langle -r\sin(t),r\cos(t)\rangle\ dt \\ \int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} \left[-B_1r\sin(t)+B_2r\cos(t)\right]\ dt \\ B_1r\cos(t) + B_2r\sin(t)\Big|_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} \\ Br + 0 \\ Br = \mu_0I \\ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{B=\frac{\mu_0I}{r}} \\ \color{red}{B = \frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r} \ \ ?}$$

I know the way to solve this problem to get rid of the dot product with $Bdr\cos(\theta)$ and to integrate wrt $B$ as constant and $C$ but where did I go wrong in my derivatino if I didn't know how to do that?

Comment: You're assuming that $\vec{B}$ is some constant field, which it isn't. The direction of $\vec{B}$ changes with $\vec{r}$, which, in your notation, means that $B_2$ is a function of $t$. As you might guess, since you don't a priori know the dependence of $B_2$ on $t$, Ampere's law is pretty useless unless one can identify some symmetry that allows this line integral to be easily calculated (which it can be in a number of important, but pathological cases - e.g. an infinite wire, or an infinite sheet of current).

Comment: Ok thank you this was helpful